# How do I set the default maximum Java heap size?

Tags: java, bash, memory

I want to set the default Java heap size to 1024m without needing to specify the 
-Xmx option every time I run a jar file.

Tried adding `export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m` to .bashrc file but it didn't work.

Comment: I  have not used Java for a while but I think it is _JAVA_OPTIONS as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613621/799759

Comment: `_JAVA_OPTIONS` is non-standard.  However, at least some versions of openJDK may have `JAVA_OPTIONS` disabled: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173712

Comment: Not Pi specific- also futile on a 1G machine

Answer (score 1):

The maximum heap size [is not the maximum amount of memory the JVM will use,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/1151724) but the heap size is what Xmx actually sets.

Regarding settings, it seems there maybe issues with `JAVA_OPTIONS`, a more bulletproof method would be to add this to `.bashrc`:

```
alias java='java -Xms1024m'
```

Or, since environment variables are interpolated in an alias:

```
alias java='java $MY_JAVA_OPTS'
export MY_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m"
```

This gives you some flexibility if you want to add or override $MY_JAVA_OPTS for some session:

```
MY_JAVA_OPTS="$MY_JAVA_OPTS -Xprof -Xdiag"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m` to /etc/profile file.